# Symfony 6.3.0 Endpoint not showing up in nelmio api interface

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I have a problem with displaying my endpoints in the nelmio api interface. this is my config:

**nelmio_api_doc.yaml**

```
nelmio_api_doc:
  areas:
    path_patterns: # an array of regexps
      - ^/api(?!/doc$)
    host_patterns:
      - ^api\.
```

**routes.yaml**

```
controllers:
  resource: ../src/Application/Controller/
  type: annotation

app.swagger_ui:
  path: /api/doc
  methods: GET
  defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger_ui }

app.swagger:
  path: /api/doc.json
  methods: GET
  defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger }


kernel:
  resource: ../src/Kernel.php
  type: annotation
```

Controller:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\OpenApi\Annotations\Tag;
class MyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/jd", name="my_route", methods={"GET"})
     *  @Tag(name="example tag") <- invoke error
     */
    public function myAction(): Response
    {
        
               return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '."wd".'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

I read that in order for nelmio api to see endpiints, you need to add markings to routes such as tag and so on, but when it gives this type of marking, I get an error:

*[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\Tag" in method Application\Controller\MyController::myAction() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in /Users/michal/Desktop/BitHub/src/AuthHub/config/../src/Application/Controller/ (which is being imported from "/Users/michal/Desktop/BitHub/src/AuthHub/config/routes.yaml "). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "annotation" type.*

anyone know how i can achieve my goal? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this happens because you are following the documentation. the documentation specifies the areas:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
   areas:
     path_patterns: # an array of regexps
       - ^/api(?!/doc$)
     host_patterns:
       - ^api\.
```

In this case host_patterns indicates that the domain you are using must start with "api." and your route paths must start with /api . Change the setting to

```
nelmio_api_doc:
   areas:
     path_patterns: # an array of regexps
       - ^/api(?!/doc$)
#host_patterns:
# - ^api\.
```

removing host_patterns from the condition. Hope this helps